# How to aling dash data table with other compoments if the app layout?

Tags: python, html, plotly-dash

I am working on a dash app that includes to graphs in two columns. One of them is a map ('graph' in the code below) and the other is a histogram('graph'-1 in the code)
When I add a dash data table below the two columns it does not align with them.
Is there a way to achieve this?

```py
app.layout = dbc.Container([
      html.Div([
        html.H1(['Farm Tree Project Scotland'],style={'text-align':'center'}),
        html.Hr()
      ]),
      dbc.Row(
          [
              dbc.Col(
                  [
                   html.Label(['Select Region'],style={'font-weight':'bold'},),
                   dcc.Dropdown(id='region-dropdown',
                                options=[{'label':i,'value':i} for i in df['AddressRegion'].unique()],
                                multi= True

                   )
                  ]
              ),       
              dbc.Col(
                  [
                  html.Div(
                          [
                          dbc.Button('Submit', id='submit-button', color='primary', className='mr-1')
                          ],style={'margin-top':'20px'}
                  )
                  ]
              )

          ]
      ),


      dbc.Row(
          [
              dbc.Col(
              [
                html.Div([
                dcc.Graph(id = 'graph',figure=update_map(df))
                ])
              ],md=8
             ),
             dbc.Col(
             [
                html.Div([
                dcc.Graph(id = 'graph-1',figure=update_bar(df))
                ])
             ],md=4
             ),
             dbc.Col(
                     [
                     html.Div(id='hidden-div')
                     ],style={'display':'none'}
             )
          ]
      ),
      
  dash_table.DataTable(
      id='table',
      columns=[{'name': col, 'id': col} for col in df.columns],
      style_cell_conditional=[{'if': {'column_id': 'Code',} ,  'display': 'None',}],
      style_table={'overflowX': 'scroll'},
      style_cell={
          'minWidth': '100px', 'width': '100px', 'maxWidth': '90px',
          'height': 'auto',
          'overflow': 'hidden',
          'textOverflow': 'ellipsis','textAlign': 'left'
      }
  )
],fluid=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit difficult to debug without a fully working example that reproduces your code.

I think you will find that the table indeed does align, but it appears to be wider because of the white padding around the plotly figures. Here is an executable example where it is easier to see that the widths are the same. I used a dark plotly theme and a darker dash theme. And I wrapped the last component in a row.

[image]

```py
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
import plotly.graph_objects as go

from dash import Dash, dcc, html, dash_table

from plotly.data import tips

df = tips()

app = Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.SLATE])

app.layout = dbc.Container([
      html.Div([
        html.H1(['Farm Tree Project Scotland'],style={'text-align':'center'}),
        html.Hr()
      ]),
      dbc.Row(
          [
              dbc.Col(
                  [
                   html.Label(['Select Region'],style={'font-weight':'bold'},),
                   dcc.Dropdown(id='region-dropdown',
                                multi= True

                   )
                  ]
              ),       
              dbc.Col(
                  [
                  html.Div(
                          [
                          dbc.Button('Submit', id='submit-button', color='primary', className='mr-1')
                          ],style={'margin-top':'20px'}
                  )
                  ]
              )

          ]
      ),

      dbc.Row(
          [
              dbc.Col(
              [
                html.Div([
                dcc.Graph(id = 'graph',figure=go.Figure().update_layout(template="plotly_dark"))
                ])
              ],md=8
             ),
             dbc.Col(
             [
                html.Div([
                dcc.Graph(id = 'graph-1',figure=go.Figure().update_layout(template="plotly_dark"))
                ])
             ],md=4
             ),
             dbc.Col(
                     [
                     html.Div(id='hidden-div')
                     ],style={'display':'none'}
             )
          ]
      ),

      dbc.Row([
          dbc.Col(
            dash_table.DataTable(
                df.to_dict("records"),
                [{"name": i, "id": i} for i in df.columns],
                page_size=20
            )
          )
      ])
])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: Your first sentence is a reason to vote to close the question, not answer it. [answer]